# JMeter looping through CSV

Tags: loops, parsing, csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

i have two CSV files which i need to loop through. I am using jp@gc - Variables from CSV file. The contents are:

File #1

```
File successfuly parsed, 10 variables found:
${1} = e79d29ec-f356-4682-b601-fa6b41c1b40a
${2} = b0c4c235-60c4-462b-bab4-89e65da8e00c
..........
```

File #2

```
File successfuly parsed, 10 variables found:
${0} = 88F6470E3E45921AEC8240A4A1C837F323C96E5DB8D06F959A42CE068E5D6477
${1} = 2A2EE03FA798D359963C47F6DB97194BB2F6E053489DBE1539367697679E2D5E
```

I have a couple of of HTTP requests which will use these values, for each run every request has to take a new value from the CSV file. I have tried using the logic controllers with no luck. Anyone who had success with something similar willing to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use 2 instances of Variables from CSV file due to variable names clash. Variables from File #1 will be overwritten by variables from File #2 (or vice versa, depending on which Variables from CSV element comes later in test plan tree)

So you have 2 options:

1. Consider switching to [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function or [CSV Data Set Config](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) for File #2
2. Change your CSV files so 1st column values will be unique